# Проблемы с кодировкой в C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, кодировка, перекодировка

Помогите разобраться с кодировкой. Хочу декодировать IBM866. Начальный текст

> ("“бв ­®ўЄ  бўп§Ё б tel...\n\nЋиЁЎЄ  б«г¦Ўл г¤ «Ґ­­®Ј® ¤®бвгЇ  797 - Џ®¤Є«озҐ­ЁҐ Є бҐаўҐаг г¤ «Ґ­­®Ј® ¤®бвгЇ  ­Ґ гбв ­®ў«Ґ­®, в Є Є Є ­Ґ ­ ©¤Ґ­ ¬®¤Ґ¬.\n\n—в®Ўл ўлўҐбвЁ бўҐ¤Ґ­Ёп ® ¤ ­­®© ®иЁЎЄҐ:\n\tўўҐ¤ЁвҐ 'hh netcfg.chm' Ё ў ‘Їа ўЄҐ\n\tўлЎҐаЁвҐ а §¤Ґ« а §аҐиҐ­Ёп Їа®Ў«Ґ¬, § вҐ¬ б®®ЎйҐ­Ё© ®Ў ®иЁЎЄ е Ё ­ ©¤ЁвҐ 797.\n").

После выполнения кода вместо русских символов абракадабра.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(PathP, Param);
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
while (!p.HasExited)
{
    q.Append(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
string r = q.ToString();

Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM866");
Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
byte[] originalByteString = srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(r);
byte[] convertedByteString = Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat,
dstEncodingFormat, originalByteString);
string finalString = dstEncodingFormat.GetString(convertedByteString);

Program.log.Info(" ID (" + ID + ") |" + "Answer: " + finalString);
```

Comment: А откуда у вас взялась строка `r`?

Comment: Строка r формируется из ответа на вызов             System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

Comment: @кириллК т.е. у вас целевой процесс сразу пишет в output в неправильной кодировке? и это нельзя поменять?

Comment: @PashaPash Да так и есть. Изначально ответ получаю в непонятном виде. Хотя в CMD ответ написан кириллицей.

Comment: @кириллК: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас лишняя операция. После `srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(r)` вы получаете исходные байты, которые нужно просто прочитать в нужной кодировке. Соответственно промежуточный `Encoding.Convert` не нужен.

Получается как-то так:

```
Encoding wrongEncoding = p.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding;
Encoding realEncoding = <тут кодировка, в которой байты на самом деле>;
byte[] originalBytes = wrongEncoding.GetBytes(r);
string result = realEncoding .GetString(originalBytes);
```

У меня, например, для

```
Encoding wrongEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
Encoding realEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
```

получается

```
ст новк  связи с tel...

Ошибк  службы уд ленного доступ  797 - Подключение к серверу уд ленного доступ  не уст новлено, т к к к не н йден модем.

Чтобы вывести сведения о д нной ошибке:
    введите 'hh netcfg.chm' и в Спр вке
    выберите р здел р зрешения проблем, з тем сообщений об ошибк х и н йдите 797.
```

Судя по всему, консольное приложение пишет в поток в кодировке CP866 (DOS), а `p.StandardOutput` считает, что эти символы в кодировке CP1251 (ANSI).

---

Возможно, более правильным решением было бы вовсе не читать из `StandardOutput`, а получить `StandardOutput.BaseStream`, и «надеть» на него `StreamReader` с правильной кодировкой. Вы видите, что при перегоне между кодировками теряются символы.

Например, вот такой код:

```
var p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
        Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%COMSPEC%"),
        "/c dir " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows))
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};
p.Start();
var stream = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(866)))
{
    string r = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

выдаёт:

```
 Том в устройстве C имеет метку CODE
 Серийный номер тома: 1061-1668

 Содержимое папки C:\WINDOWS

12.03.2018  20:44    <DIR>          .
12.03.2018  20:44    <DIR>          ..
29.09.2017  14:46    <DIR>          addins
22.10.2017  10:32    <DIR>          appcompat
16.03.2018  02:21    <DIR>          apppatch
23.03.2018  21:43    <DIR>          AppReadiness
```

и т. д.

---

Откуда получить кодовую страницу 866 программным путём? Для этого нужно знать системную локаль. Её можно, кажется, добыть, запомнив `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` в начале программы

```
var systemCI = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
```

или через P/Invoke:

```
int systemlcid = GetSystemDefaultLCID();
var systemCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(systemlcid);
```

`GetSystemDefaultLCID` определяется как

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetSystemDefaultLCID();
```

Имея локаль, можно получить кодовую страницу так:

```
var oemCodePage = systemCI.TextInfo.OEMCodePage;
var oemEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(oemCodePage);
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Comment: @кириллК: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!