# Проблемы с кодировкой c#

Tags: c#, кодировка

Всех приветствую. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я вывожу информацию из cmd(В моём случае это голый ping), получаю крокозябры:

```
€бЇ®«м§®ў ­ЁҐ: ping [-t] [-a] [-n <зЁб«®>] [-l <а §¬Ґа>] [-f] [-i <TTL>]
                    [-v <TOS>] [-r <зЁб«®>] [-s <зЁб«®>] 
                    [[-j <бЇЁб®Є_г§«®ў>] | [-k <бЇЁб®Є_г§«®ў>]]
                    [-w <ўаҐ¬п_®¦Ё¤ ­Ёп>] [-R] [-S < ¤аҐб_Ёбв®з­ЁЄ >]
                    [-c бҐЄжЁп] [-p] [-4] [-6] Є®­Ґз­л©_г§Ґ«
```

Пытался переводить в разные кодировки, но не вышло. Объясните - как это решить и что я делаю не так?

Код:

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = psi;
            proc.Start();
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("...").GetBytes(result);

            string b = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            result = b;
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804186/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Помогло, спасибо